# how to set only faultcode in soap response?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, soap, cxf

I send fault code using this code

```
SOAPFault soapFault = SOAPFactory.newInstance().createFault();
soapFault.setFaultCode("120");
soapFault.setFaultString("search critera not match");
throw  new SOAPFaultException(soapFault);
```

but in response I get

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:120</faultcode>
         <faultstring>search critera not match</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I do not want `<faultcode>soap:120</faultcode>` soap in faultcode we want only 120 as fault code like this `<faultcode>120</faultcode>`

what changes I need to do for getting the below result

```
<faultcode>120</faultcode>
```